# Set cell value in devexpress focusedrowhandle from combo box that is not in the gridview

Tags: c#, devexpress

i want to set the combobox text in a column TECNICO when a buttom is pressed.

But in runtime i cannot show the set value in the column TECNICO

```
private void asing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ( tecnicos.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlConnection con = conec.ObtenerCon();
                    SqlCommand sel = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RTID_STATUS WHERE ID_RTID='" + gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue(colID_RTID) + "'", con);
                    SqlDataReader rs = sel.ExecuteReader();
                        if (rs.Read())
                        {
                            con.Close();
                            SqlConnection con1 = conec.ObtenerCon();
                            MessageBox.Show(" hay :\t" + gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue(colID_RTID));
                            SqlCommand up = new SqlCommand("UPDATE RTID_STATUS SET ID_TECH='" + idtec(tecnicos.Text) + "'", con1);
                            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, tec,tecnicos.Text.ToString());
                            gridView1.RefreshRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle);
                            SqlDataReader resu = up.ExecuteReader();
                            con1.Close();
                        }
                        else
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the value exist in your RepositoryItemComboBoxEdit's Items collection?